# Message Error while generating report by BIRT Report Engine 4.5.0

Tags: java, report, birt

Here is my scenario.
I run my report by using Report engine bat file by issuing command like:

%BIRT_HOME%\ReportEngine genReport.bat -f PDF -o temp.PDF -p "param1=1000001" -p "param2=en" -p "param3=admin" Reports\invoicingreport.rptdesign".

When I set the param1 to a value that produces about 200 pages the output file is generated fine but when I switch the param1 to the other value that produces 2000 pages (I know it because in Birt Report Designer it works) then the report is computed for a while and after a few seconds I get several lines of "java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown source) " error message.

[View of the Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD2IW.jpg)

Comment: Post the stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Nov 11, 2015 10:31:35 AM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask handleFatalExceptions
SEVERE: Error happened while running the report.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:101)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I fixed the issue by increasing the stack size to 1024KB (-Xss1024k )